# Linux Mint : node not found inside VS Terminal

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, terminal, path, linux-mint

i was a Win10 user, and I transitioned to Linux Mint 21 a day ago. Didn't realize that LM21 is the newest version of Mint, freshly released a few days ago.

When I run `node -v` in the terminal I get 'v16.16.0' 
When I run `npm -v` in the terminal I get '8.11.0'

I installed VS Code, and now I need **npm**, but when I type the same commands, like the commands from above in the VS Code terminal, I get the following error: 
sh-5.1$ node -v 
`sh: node: command not found`

sh-5.1$ npm -v 
`sh: npm: command not found`

What could be the problem ?

Also my "name" in the VS Code terminal is 'sh-5.1' which is strange

When I type `$PATH` in the linux terminal I get `bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/dachalinux/nodejs/bin: No such file or directory`

When I type `echo $PATH` I get `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/dachalinux/nodejs/bin`

Let me know if you need additional info.  
Thanks in advance for the help <3

Answer (score 0):

Do you use VS Code version from Package Manager? Flathub warns about potential problems with this version. As far as I remember, there were metioned also some terminal issues. I suggest to download VS Code directly from its website: https://code.visualstudio.com/download.